# How to say "I gotchu" (I have your back) in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, inglés

There is a phrase "I gotchu" (I got you / I have your back), which is fairly new to the English vernacular, and has a connotation of "Don't worry, I will take care of everything, so that you don't have to worry about a thing", "I have everything covered", or even "Don't worry, I'm here for you, I will catch you if you fall." It conveys safety and protection, especially when said by a man to a woman. How would I capture these nuances in Spanish?

Comment: The phrase is I got you. "I gotchu" is just somebody's way of trying to write how it is said. Anyway, one way is: Me ocupo de ti.

Comment: Yes, obviously that's how it's correctly written in English. But as you acknowledge, it's not even pronounced "I got you", the pronunciation is actually "I gotchu", so people are starting to write it that way these days. Language evolves over time, and this is a recent evolution. Thanks for the suggestion, that seems like a good translation!

Comment: Well, for me kinda, wanna etc. etc. are all dialogue uses. For those writers who want to try and mimic spoken language. It's funny because I see wanna on Netflix even when a character says: wanta instead.

Comment: @LukeHutchison I suspect the pronunciation is only *I gotchu* in American English. The slurring between ‘t’ and ‘you’ to produce ‘chu’ isn’t common in British English IMHO

Comment: @Traveller I agree, gotcha is usual in the UK

Comment: @Traveller you are right. Actually I'm a Kiwi, but I do live in the US, so I have mostly exposure to US English these days. In England or the former colonies (except probably in Canada), you'd actually have to say "I've got you", or even the full "I've got your back".

Comment: Buenas, en la Argentina decimos ‘no te preocupes, yo te banco’ o también ‘no te preocupes, te hago la gamba’. Espero que te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 1):

We usually say: "Yo te cubro", or the full form "Yo te cubro las espaldas". For example, when an employee needs to leave to the doctor, a coworker can say "Ve, yo te cubro"

Answer (score 1):

Going based on your use case, I think saying "No te preocupes" and/or "Yo me encargo" better relates that "don't worry about it"/"I'll take care of it" assurance you're going for.